# How to draw a 3D convex hull of a set of points with styling

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

I´m trying to obtain the convex hull (with transparent faces) of a small number of points. I would like the Plot to have

- the points shown with small spheres
- numbers 1, 2, 3, ... along the axes

Here is what I have tried.

```
p = {{2, 1, 6}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 2, 5}, {3, 5, 4}}
ListPointPlot3D[p, PlotStyle -> {Red, "Sphere", Large}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}, {0, 6}}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Could you help me.

Comment: In V10 you could use `ConvexHullMesh` to generate the hull and then `HighlighMesh` for the styling.

Comment: @user21 but... is available the version 10 of Mathematica?. I see the web and I can see mathematica v9 but not v10 http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/

Comment: @MikaIke "Mathematica 10 Just Released!
See What's New »"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Version 10, we can compute the convex hull using `ConvexHullMesh`

```
p = {{2, 1, 6}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 2, 5}, {3, 5, 4}}

chull = ConvexHullMesh[p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which we can style using `HighlightMesh`

```
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]], Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.1]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ok. Only 1 question. Do you know how to view the 3 axis and the numers in the axis 1,2,3,4,...   ?

Comment: @MikaIke, what do you mean by axis?

Comment: @MikaIke Add `, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True` into `Show`.